# Update cart quantity only updating one product

Tags: php, session

I am trying to use a single button to update all my cart quantity and it's not working

I have added the product to cart via sessions, display products from cart now all I'm trying to do is to update the quantity and it's not updating

```
if(isset($_POST["updates"])) { 
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {

        $pid=$_POST['proid'];
        $qty =$_POST['quantity'];

        foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['item_id'] == $_POST['proid']) {

                $_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$key]['item_qty'] = $_POST['quantity'];
            }
        } 

         $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array_values($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);

         header('Refresh:0');
    }
}
```

@RiggsFolly here is the print result

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [item_id] => 24 
            [item_name] => something 
            [item_price] => 800 
            [item_qty] => 1 
        ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
            [item_id] => 26 
            [item_name] => Fishly 
            [item_price] => 450 
            [item_qty] =>
        ) 
)
```

Comment: Try adding `print_r($SESSION['shopping_cart']);` before and after this line `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array_values($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);` that may tell you the problem

Comment: And it would be useful if you pasted the results of those 2 `print_r()` statements into your question if that does not help you

Comment: tried that not getting any print out

Comment: then write the output to a file

Comment: @RiggsFolly here is the print result Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 24 [item_name] => something [item_price] => 800 [item_qty] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 26 [item_name] => Fishly [item_price] => 450  [item_qty] => ) )

Comment: Is that before or after the `$_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array_values($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);` line

Comment: After @RiggsFolly

Comment: So also do one before please